# Multiple buttons call JQuery, need to know which one was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have multiple buttons which can call the same JQuery function. Example of html:

```
<tr><td>...</td>
    <td><button class="modify" name="8">Modify</button></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>...</td>
    <td><button class="modify" name="9">Modify</button></td>
</tr>
```

and so on...

And my JQuery function:

```
$(function() {
    var id = $("button").attr("name");
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 240,
        modal: true,
        buttons: { 
            "Submit": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'my_http',
                    type: 'POST',
                data: $my_data,
                }); 
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }   
        }
    });
    $(".modify").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
});
```

As you can see I need to now which button was clicked (I retrieve it's name at the beginning of the dialog function). But since its "clickability" is determined by the class, not id, I get the first id in the list (8 in this case, even though the 9th was clicked).

How can I know which one was clicked? If I use classes, I do not know ids (names), if I use ids, how can I know that it was clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `click()` method:

```
$(".modify").click(function () {
    /* 'this' is the clicked DOM node,
        '$(this)' is the clicked DOM node wrapped in a jQuery object. */
    var clickedButtonName = this.name;
    /* or $(this).prop('name'), but don't use jQuery to access a property that
       can be returned by the DOM API, it's needlessly expensive. */
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: Thank you David, but how to send it to the dialog (I send this name to the php function by POST, it is included in $my_data)?

Comment: What do you want it to *do* in the dialog? Without more specific information, I can only point you to [the API for the `dialog()` widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: I want to send it to the php function: url: 'my_http',                    type: 'POST',data: "id="+ id

Comment: Solved by adding var nameButton = this.name;   $('#dialog').data('id', nameButton); in the click() function and         var id = $(this).data('id'); in the dialog buttons submit function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first parameter of the click function like so:

[Click here for live demo!](http://jsbin.com/IRoTENa/2/edit)

```
$(".modify").click(function (e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```